# asp.net create radiobutton from dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, radio-button

I have a dataset containing many items including "blockID" and a "blockName".
I want to populate radiobuttonlists which their value will be the "blockName" property, and I need them to be grouped by the "blockID" property. i.e. the user can choose only one "blockName" from each "blockID".
I am using c#
Is that possible?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I made an example below, i know it's not a DataSet but still a pretty good example of how you could do it. It would still be possible to map from the DataSet for this structure because it would really makes things easier in my opinion.

Given the following block class for the DataSource item:

```
public class Block
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<string> BlockNames { get; set; }

    public Block(int id, params string[] names)
    {
        ID = id;
        BlockNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in names)
        {
            BlockNames.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

You see, with this class, the `BlockNames` are already grouped with a single block's `ID`.

In your ASPX/ASCX markup, define a `Repeater` and subscribe to the `OnItemDataBound` event:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDummy" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptDummy_OnItemDataBound">
</asp:Repeater>
```

On the `OnItemDataBound` event, dynamically add the `RadioButtonLists` with each BlockName being a different RadioButton, and each `RadioButtonList` being of a different BlockID:

```
protected void rptDummy_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Block blk = (Block)e.Item.DataItem;
        RadioButtonList list = new RadioButtonList();
        list.ID = "rblBlocks";
        list.Attributes.Add("BlockID", blk.ID.ToString());

        foreach (string item in blk.BlockNames)
        {
            list.Items.Add(new ListItem(item, item));
        }

        e.Item.Controls.Add(list);
    }
}
```

Bind the repeater:

```
List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();

blocks.Add(new Block(1, "BlockName1", "BlockName2", "BlockName3"));
blocks.Add(new Block(2, "BlockName4", "BlockName5"));
blocks.Add(new Block(3, "BlockName6"));

rptDummy.DataSource = blocks;
rptDummy.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.
There is one thing I think I didn't explain good, the "block" that I talked about is in a database and we use a procedure to get it from the db.
the procedures return us a dataset.
that dataset contains many "blockID"'s and "blockName"'s which that we have to separate into radio button groups according to the "blockID"
thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, my answer covers the scenario of many BlockIDs and many Blocknames related to them. I am aware that you don't have the data structure i used, but you could definitely turn the `Dataset` you have into a `List` of `Block` objects that were used. As i said, it is a good alternative for what you want.